# Why is my SQL statement so slow executed on Postgre?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-performance

I have a table with 1.5 million rows, now I need to do a data migration on the table: First add a column on the table, then update the column to be the same as another column in the same table:

```
UPDATE order SET customer_username = order.customer_phone;
```

The statement of adding a column finishes instantly, but the statement above take hours. What costs so much time? And how can I improve the performance of the statement, so that I can reduce the down time for production servers when performing migration?

1. The customer_username is VARCHAR field, customer_phone is a TextField.
2. There is index on both fields.

And is there any postgre configuration I can fine tune to improve the migration speed?

Comment: 1. should not matter
2. you better set value on new column and then create index on it

Comment: This statement takes a long time because it rewrites the whole table. If it's a big table, it'll take time.

Comment: If you have a foreign key asociated it must control it. Drop de FK and recreate it before the update, and before the recreation of the index.